# Internet Explorer and textbox

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Some of my co-workers are facing a problem with Internet Explorer. When they reach a page, a textbox is supposed to show a postal code on a french format (5 digits).

The point is, the textbox does what it's supposed to do on most cases, but when the postal code starts with a 0, it only shows the last 4 digits. The textbox's text is binded to a sql server database

```
<asp:TextBox ID="postal_code" runat="server" Text = '<%# Bind("postal_code") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

and the postal codes are registred in the database as varchar (e.g.: '08300', '17560', ...), so there's no cast from int to string. It works perfectly on other browsers (Mozilla, Chrome).

Can somebody explain why Internet Explorer does that? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you share what html is rendered for the textbox in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the bug resolved itself after deleting cookies, so I guess that's coming from Internet Explorer version (7.X for some coworkers). I tried on Edge, but nothing happened.

Just in case, if that can help somebody in the future, deleting cookies might prove useful, or changing the browser or keeping it on last version.